# How to check if value selected in jquery selectable if not throw an error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a jQuery selectable plugin placed in one of my ASP.NET MVC views. Like below:

```
<ol class="ui-selectable" id="selectable">
    @{
        var size = Model.AvailableSizes.Split(',');
        foreach (var item in size)
        {
            <li class="btn red-mint" style="margin:10px 0">@item</li>
        }
    }
</ol>
```

Now I would like to throw an error on a `button click` lets say "Please Select a size" html error in my view not an alert or something. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can achive using jquery refer [API document](http://api.jqueryui.com/selectable/#event-selected)

```
 $("#selectable").selectable({
    selected: function(event, ui){ 
        // mark as selected
    },
    unselected: function(event, ui){
        //mark as unselected
    }
});
```